# Net gravity problem ... how to solve?

Tags: physics

[image]

So far, I have:

$$\dfrac{G  \times(2\cdot10^{-3})^2}{\sqrt{??}} $$ ???

What's next?

Comment: They dont accept questions. Can you help?

Comment: You have to understand the underlying physics. *Hint*: do the gravitational effect of $m_1$ and $m_4$ on $m_5$ cancel each other out? What about the gravitational pull of $m_3$ and $m_2$ on $m_5$?

Comment: m1 nd 4 cancel.

Comment: I need help with figuring out the denominator

Comment: *Hint*: You have to apply the Newton's gravitational law _twice_, instead of _once_. Do you see why? Also *hint*: which is more powerful: gravitational pull of $m_3$ on $m_5$ or $m_2$ on $m_5$? What is the *net effect* of these two gravitational forces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the equation you're using is incorrect.  Please refer to the [correct version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Modern_form).

Second, you have realized that the gravitational force of $m_1$ on $m_5$ and $m_4$ on $m_5$ cancel each other out, because the mass of $m_1$ and $m_4$ are the same, and so are their distance from $m_5$.  This observation speeds things up.

Lastly, to lead you in the correct direction, the magnitude of the gravitational force of $m_2$ on $m_5$ is
$$
  G\cdot\frac{m_2 m_5}{d^2},
$$
where $d$ is the distance from $m_2$ to $m_5$, and the direction is to the north east.

What about the gravitational force of $m_3$ on $m_5$? What is its magnitude and direction? What is the net effect of these two gravitational forces? What about the net effect of all four gravitational forces on $m_5$?

If you can figure out these issues step by step, you will have learnt something.